# GMAT Math Problem, what is the value of $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, intuition

**You must choose one of the statements below to answer this question**

What is the value of $x$?

1. $x^4 = 2,401$
2. $x^5 = 16,807$

**Statement 1** ALONE is sufficient to answer the question, but statement 2 alone is NOT sufficient.

**Statement 2** ALONE is sufficient to answer the question, but statement 1 alone is NOT sufficient.

**BOTH statements 1 and 2 TOGETHER**
are sufficient to answer the question, but NEITHER statement ALONE is sufficient.

**Each statement ALONE** is sufficient to answer the question.
Statement 1 and 2

**TOGETHER are NOT** sufficient to answer the question.

The correct answer according to the GMAT is  **Statement 2** ALONE is sufficient to answer the question, but statement 1 alone is NOT sufficient, in other words, you may find THE value of $x$ when raised to the fifth power, but this isn't true! $x$ has five values, five roots! Its value could be any one of them! Am I missing something? I would argue together they are not sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: I think they are assuming that $x$ is real. Real fifth roots are unique but real fourth roots are not.

Comment: Imagine being a mathematician but being considered wrong because they use a "smaller" domain.

For complex $x$, together would be enough as we can divide the second by the first one to get $x = 7$, then substitute this to check it really satisfied both equations.

Comment: @RobArthan I assume as much too, but they can't make such an assumption without being explicit especially on the MATH section! For now, I will always assume numbers are real unless stated otherwise, but I can imagine I will be deceived anyway

Comment: @Azlif I missed that! Then there goes another super valid reason their answer is wrong, this is frustrating as hell!

Comment: I agree that it is very poor practice to set a question like this without stating all the necessary assumptions to the intended GMAT audience. (If it was an Algebra 1 audience, then maybe it would be OK, but it's not.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, the domain where we talk about "the numbers" is really important. It is then important to know whether they are using real numbers or complex numbers. And it is also important for THEM to specify the scope of their test. Since not everyone is a commoner, you know. Many mathematicians(or at least somebody who knew complex numbers) out there also takes the GMAT test (I think).

The answer to this question then depends on the domain of $x$, it is even possible for EVERY STATEMENT to be true with the appropriate domain.

For real $x$, the first equation yields $x = -7$ or $x = 7$ while the second gives us $x = 7$ so the second only would sufficient.

For complex $x$, $7$ satisfies both equations. And by dividing the second with the first gives us $x = 7$. So both would be sufficient.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer fully :)